# unexpected reboot then unable to boot

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, memory, macos

> Model Name:  MacBook Pro   Model Identifier: MacBookPro10,1
>   Processor Name:   Intel Core i7   Processor Speed:    2.3 GHz   Number of
>   Processors:   1   Total Number of Cores:  4   L2 Cache (per Core):    256 KB
>   L3 Cache: 6 MB   Memory:  8 GB   Boot ROM Version:    MBP101.00F6.B00
>   SMC Version (system): 2.3f36

I have some weird issue with my Macbook Pro Retina mid 2012.

It turns itself of by itself, then if I turn it on it won't boot. I force shutdown and turn it on again I get just a black screen.

Ran First Aid on the disk -- did not find any issue -- did a OS update, same issue, reset SMC, PRAM -- the issue remains.

It's a bit random but usually once it is turned off, I can't have the system fully boot again (either black screen or reboots in loop.) I usually have to wait a while which make me think it's a hardware issue, but the computer doesn't seem that hot.

Any idea of what can I do?

I suppose a vanilla install will be my next step but I don't think that is going to solve anything.

Comment: does it do that on battery or even with power cable.

Comment: Yes same behaviour with A/C or on batterie

Comment: did you run Apple Hardware Test

Comment: Yes m, unable to run diagnostics, DEC500, I guess is the ram

Comment: why would you say that is the RAM ? how much RAM does the Activity Monitor shows ?

Comment: install and run EtreChek `https://etrecheck.com/` and see what it says.

Comment: downloading now, in the mean time at the restart I have an alert Panic Medic Boot, a third party kernel extension was preventing the machine from successfully booting ... update : as I run the test the screen immediately turn black

Comment: So I managed to install the Apple Diagnostic Tools on a usb stick result : alert apple hardware test has detected an error. 4SNS/1/40000001 : IDOR- 0.003 with apparently is motherboard related :(